# Parent Node not visible in the quick launch on browsing from sub child

Tags: 2013, navigation, quick-launch, term-store

I have created a multi level quick launch using Term Store. It is working fine in terms of the heirarchy but when I traverse from a sub child to some page in the heirarchy the quick launch gets changed. It does not display the menu for the parent links.

I want it to be consistent across the site i.e. displaying the entire navigation on all the pages. Please provide some inputs on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using absolute URLs, but after replacing them with relative URLs in the `Term Store` it is working fine (i.e. to say that I am getting a consistent navigation structure throughout the site).